# How could a winged human hide their wings?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, fauna, winged-humans

In my world there are ''angels'' which have 4ft long wings and can't fly. As of late, these 'angels' have been hunt down and they must hide. How can a winged human hide their wings?

Comment: Its to bad they won't be able to fly because you won't be able to get though the TSA with wings on your back

Comment: @JGaines I was about to upvote your answer then realized it was a comment. I would write up an answer if I were you.

Comment: X-) Well, I was hoping the creator would give me a yea or nay on if they need to be able to fly later or if this species was *ever* able to fly. But I suppose Batman can just toss out some support if that's not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that each wing is four feet long as measured from shoulder to feather tip. Folded, a wing is slightly shorter - I'm mentally estimating based on my parrot - the tips of these wings could reach to the upper thighs (though wings you might sit on seems like a design flaw). In that case, a long coat or jacket is your best bet, and made of a fabric that's opaque and doesn't pill readily. There's also no need to keep the wings intact if the angels cannot fly - trim off the feathers and the weight and volume of the wings will be reduced, making them easier to conceal. If the feathers grow back, this would be a less objectionable solution compared to removing the wings entirely. And depending on how the wings are jointed, an angel might wrap their wings together with the equivalent of an Ace bandage to prevent accidental reflexive flapping, if they do that.

However, if I assume you mean a four foot wingspan (from feather tip to feather tip), and if the wings were flexible in the right way, an angel could wrap their wings flat around their torso and cover them with a corset, allowing the wings to be hidden under ordinary clothing.

Of course, any solution is going to be modified based on how much discomfort it causes the winged humans. If they're trying to escape genocide, the daily pain of binding their wings would likely hamper their success.

Answer (score 11):

Let's see:

- Magic
- Big overcoats
- Cut them off

That just about covers it (pun intended)

Comment: Augh! Correct answer in list format! Voting stalemate!

Comment: @Frostfyre - not only is this my shortest answer _ever_, it also offered me an opportunity to include a terrible play on words, and took my daily rep count to 200. It's basically the perfect end to my day

Answer (score 3):

Your species will need to either;

- Hide the wings using a harness under clothing (like archangel in Xmen 3)
- Where some some of large clothing piece like a trench coat or a cape
- Suck up their pride and cut of the wings
- Always wear a backpack with the inside cut out
- Paint their wings in hand-wavium and magic

Short story even shorter unless your angel is a holy angel and has magic on their side or they are will to cut off those limbs, clothing is your best bet

Comment: It's quite probable that hunters would cop on to the trench-coats or backpacks and soon enough people wearing those would become targets too.... Though I suppose that depends on the setting.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to have them be able to hide the wings, you might be able to make them collapsable. Where they can collapse the wings into their back most of the way and then fold any extra bits flat behind the back where a shirt can easily cover them. Since they can't fly they don't need to be that thick or support weight. You could have this species' biology basically have cavities for wing storage near the sholderblades, making some room by moving organs around and such.

Answer (score 1):

One could fold them across the back and then wear clothes backwards such that the wings appeared to be a very well endowed bust.  One would then turn one's head 90 degrees as if fascinated by something to the side.

Probably other accoutrements should lend credence to the idea that you are the sort of person who might have such a magnificent bust, and have knees that bend the wrong way.