# How could a winged human hide very big wings

Tags: clothing, avian, winged-humans, angels, flight

So I've seen a question similar to this one, but the wings were much shorter.
I've got a character that's about 5ft tall and has wings from about his shoulders to his calves. Think avian-human hybrid (he was one of the first test tube babies) he's unique and wants to hide his wings when he's going into towns and such.
How would I hide his wings? he couldn't just hide them with a jacket because of the length.
the difference between this and the other question is my character is very short. his wings are about the length of his entire torso, and my character can fly, albeit not easily, but he can fly.

Comment: If it can keep the wings close enough to its body I would suggest some big robes, like some kind of monk

Comment: A difference of one foot doesn't make this a unique question.

Comment: Concur with rek --- as written, the questions are functionally identical. Do your winged folk do anything with their wings that would sufficiently alter the question and thus make it not a duplicate?

Comment: I like Gargoyles where most characters would tuck their wings around their body when they were in doors or needed to reduce the body width for reasons.   Typically this resulted in a cape or cloak like effect of the wing (Used by Goliath, Hudson, and Broadway), or a wrap under the armpits much like a towel around a woman (used mostly by Demona and (the very much male) Brooklyn).   The only recurring character who didn't do this was Lexington, who's wings extended from his arms to legs like a flying squirrel.  He still had the two extra limbs which acted as supports half-way down the membrane.

Comment: Your edit doesn't tell us anything that can't be answered by the [other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41239/how-could-a-winged-human-hide-their-wings), you may have tweaked your question, but not made it clear how the differences are not addressed there. You can [edit] again if you wish. People can have [long coats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatcoat).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Giant Hiking Backpack**

[image]

He's never going to be able to hide them under clothing. It'll be too obvious there's way too much unaccounted mass there unless he also wears a fatsuit. Your best bet is to hide them under a large accessory it's seen as reasonably normal to wear on your back.

So give him a fake hiking backpack that doesn't actually have anything inside it. Make it go from the top of his head to below his back, and make it zip closed around his wings and hide them safely inside.

Another plus side is that, as the picture demonstrates, this works regardless of the weather, whereas any kind of solution involving bulky clothing is gonna look odd come summertime.

Comment: As far as I remember there is a fantasy race in Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, the Kenku, composed of winged humanoids that do exactly this. In later editions they are no longer winged it seems, but I remember them being so clearly in AD&D.

Answer (score 2):

***Pretend* to dress up in costume.**

Although I think that the two answers posted before mine are certainly more likely to work in an everyday situation, but if your character needs to potentially make a quick escape using his wings, he could dress the rest of his body as some extreme cosplay character or costume, which would not impinge his wings, but would definitely get some strange looks from passerby. This disguise works especially well during Halloween, or if he is part of a group of young people all wearing costumes.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

I believe that if your character can bind their wings, using two straps, they could

1. Hide them under a robe or a larger jacket of sorts.
2. They can break the straps in an extreme situation.

They could be held far back, and while it might cramp a bit, I think it's better than carrying around a giant backpack. The only issue is that if your character breaks off the straps in a situation that requires quick action, then you have to get new ones.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that gets "broken off"?

Comment: Also, you don't really need to explain that you're "new"! In a couple weeks you'll be "old" and this answer will be here long after you're gone.